# ImageResizer license not working under Azure website

Tags: imageresizer

I own a performance license for ImageResizing for the domain **azure.content.bloc.net** with A record to a Azure website
See example url to a image hosted in azure here:

http://azure.content.bloc.net/logo/200000195/1767/2015/12/15/ny%20ove2r.jpg?width=300

But the resizer.debug.ashx returns the following error:
resizer configuration(Error):   No license found for domain **bloccontent.azurewebsites.net** - features installed: R4Performance or R4BlobProviders

http://azure.content.bloc.net/resizer.debug.ashx

How do we fix this problem?

---

**Update:**

We have changed our setup and we are using azure VM machine instead. only binding that exists in IIS is azure.content.bloc.net

resizer.debug page is showing 0 issues (http://azure.content.bloc.net/resizer.debug.ashx)

However, we are still getting the red dot on all photos: http://azure.content.bloc.net/profile/200000195/757/2015/12/10/

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer Performance licenses must be used only for public-facing domains where the HTTP host header recieved by the app matches the domain key.

As specified in the product description, we suggest an Elite license for load-balanced deployments where an internal domain is used instead.

I suggest looking at your HTTP logs to see what HOST headed is being sent to your application. If possible, configure your CDN or load balancers to address the server with a subdomain of the purchased domain. It is likely that you cannot actually do an A record on azure websites.

Comment: Ok, so now we have changed our setup and we are using a azure VM machine instead. only binding that exists in IIS is azure.content.bloc.net and now the resizer.debug page is showing 0 issues (http://azure.content.bloc.net/resizer.debug.ashx)

However, we are still getting the red dot on all photos:

http://azure.content.bloc.net/profile/200000195/757/2015/12/10/bba57100d4bb285b17c88fe487cc91c9.jpg?width=500

Comment: Hi Nathanael, we are still having the red dot issue. What do we need to do to resolve this?

Comment: 2016-01-05 14:09:26 100.78.78.16 GET /imagecache/1ea9/7f7eebee5f15da34bb4733baad119e8dfc207460f85bbc4a7d6a22b9f3aff0a9.png width=50&height=50&mode=crop&scale=both&anchor=topcenter 80 - 139.112.164.4 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/43.0.2357.130+Safari/537.36 http://markane-il.idrettenonline.no/p/11327/nyhende azure.content.bloc.net 200 0 0 364

Comment: Delete the imagecache; some dots may be cached.

Comment: We removed <diskcache> now, but we still got the red dot

Comment: new log:

2016-01-06 10:27:29 100.78.78.16 GET /redactor/200000195/1397/2016/1/5/635875845309383684arenakart-ullsheim.png width=50&height=50&mode=crop&scale=both&anchor=topcenter 80 - 88.88.120.220 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+CPU+OS+8_3+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/600.1.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/8.0+Mobile/12F69+Safari/600.1.4 http://markane-il.idrettenonline.no/p/11330/nyhende-(ski) azure.content.bloc.net 200 0 0 335

Comment: any more ideas nathanael?

Comment: I think this will require a live debugging session. I have never seen this before.

Comment: I emailed you my skype username